# Disable use of mic + camera for mobile file upload

Tags: angular, google-chrome, typescript, firefox, mobile

We're writing a web application in Angular and have a file upload function. When I click the button to upload, mobile browsers (Firefox on Android, Chrome on Android and iOS) request permission to access the microphone and camera. I have tried to restrict the types of files that can be uploaded, which works on a desktop browser but has no apparent effect on mobile.

Here's the code for the upload button in question:

```
public getFile() {
    const input: HTMLInputElement = document.createElement('input');
    input.type = 'file';
    input.name = 'features';
    input.accept = '.json, .gml, .kml';
    input.onchange = (event) => {
        this.handleUpload(event);
    };
    document.body.appendChild(input);
    input.click();
    document.body.removeChild(input);
}
```

I have found this [related bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1362919) for Firefox that at least indicates that there is some processing of the permissions happening.

Also related: [How does Firefox for Android use the permissions it requests?](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-firefox-android-use-permissions-it-requests)

Is there any way to restrict the input further so that the microphone and camera permissions are not requested?